# jquery - reload function, lose variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

lets say i have this function:

```
$("#click").click(function myFunction(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   myFunction();
});
```

Now, obviously, after the click event, id == "click", but when the function reloads, id == undefined.
Is there a way that i can reload the function without redefining the variable?

Comment: Please add html also...

Comment: What do you mean by 'reload the function'? The `id` variable is only within scope of the click handler.

Comment: line 3, "myFunction();" reloads the function - calls the function again without the click event.

Comment: Please provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're recursively calling a closure function. Here's a working copy where you can use a callback function to access the variable:

```
$("#click").click(function() {
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   console.log("click id: " + id);
   myFunction(id);
});

function myFunction(id) {
   console.log("id: " + id);
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/irmoathlete/4nwmw11r/)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling a closure function recursively. In the context where the closure function `myFunction` is a `callback` to the click event handler, `$(this)` resolves to the element on which the `click` was performed and so you will be able to get the `id` attribute within the function. However, when you call it again, `$(this)` doesn't resolve to the same element which is why your `id` will be `undefined`.